# Where is the error in my Triggers

Tags: oracle, plsql, database-trigger

Hey Im Looking at this Triggers for hours now can someone help me ?
These Triggers Are for a Database appenrently . I made sure all those tables exist.S

```
create or replace TRIGGER postleizahl_check
 BEFORE  
 INSERT  or  UPDATE   on  Kunden
 FOR EACH ROW


BEGIN
DECLARE PLZ varchar(5) ;
SET PLZ := (Select PLZ from PLZVERZEICHNIS where Ort = new.Ort) ;
if :new.Postleitzahl = PLZ then 
INSERT INTO Kunden (KUNDEN_NUMMER,NACHNAME, VORNAME, STRAßE , POSTLEITZAHL, HAUSNUMMER,ORT )
VALUES (new.KUNDEN_NUMMER,new.NACHNAME,new.VORNAME, new.STRAßE ,new.POSTLEITZAHL, new.HAUSNUMMER,new.ORT ); 
else 
 RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR 
           (-20001, 'PLZ Exestiert nicht. ');
end if ;

end;


CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER nachbestellen
AFTER INSERT ON Bestellungen
For Each Row
BEGIN
if Bestellungen.Datum = GETDATE THEN 
INSERT INTO LIEFERANTENBESTELLUNG(Artikel_Nummer,LIEFERANTEN_NUMMER,DATUM,Artikel_Name)
VALUES(new.Artikel_Nummer,new.Artikel_Namen,new.DATUM,new.LIEFERANTEN_NUMMER);
END IF ;
END;
```

Comment: What rdbms are you working with?

Comment: we are working with Oracle and sql developer

Comment: What is the error you get?

Comment: What is the problem? You're asking a bunch of strangers on the internet to spend their time helping you: the least you could do is invest some of your time framing a decent question.

Answer (score 1):

Your declare statement must come before your begin, and 'set' is a SQL*Server construct, not Oracle. All of your 'new' should be prefixed with a colon (:);

Additional comment: varchar is a valid type, but in Oracle you should be using varchar2. Currently they work the same way in Oracle, but Oracle reserves the right to change it in the future, most likely to conform to the ANSI standard for varchar.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER postleizahl_check
    BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE
    ON kunden
    FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
    plz   VARCHAR (5);
BEGIN
    plz   := (SELECT plz
                FROM plzverzeichnis
               WHERE ort = :new.ort);

    IF :new.postleitzahl = plz
    THEN
        INSERT INTO kunden (
                   kunden_nummer, nachname, vorname
                 , straße, postleitzahl, hausnummer
                 , ort
                    )
             VALUES (
                        :new.kunden_nummer, :new.nachname, :new.vorname
                      , :new.straße, :new.postleitzahl, :new.hausnummer
                      , :new.ort
                    );
    ELSE
        raise_application_error (-20001, 'PLZ Exestiert nicht. ');
    END IF;
END;

CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER nachbestellen
    AFTER INSERT
    ON bestellungen
    FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    IF bestellungen.datum = getdate
    THEN
        INSERT INTO lieferantenbestellung (
                   artikel_nummer, lieferanten_nummer, datum
                 , artikel_name
                    )
             VALUES (
                        :new.artikel_nummer, :new.artikel_namen, :new.datum
                      , :new.lieferanten_nummer
                    );
    END IF;
END;
```

Comment: Sholdn't the assignment of the `PLZ` variable be something like `select plz into plz from ...`?

Comment: Thanks for the help 
it has to be  select plz into plz from .... 
also  IF bestellungen.datum = getdate doesnt work
but everything else worked

Comment: Your IF statement fails for 2 reasons.

Comment: Your IF statement fails for 2 reasons. First,  getdate is not an Oracle function (at least an Oracle supplied). Second, the reference to datum should be to :new.datum not to the table.column name. Also keep in mind that Oracle dates contain both the date and the time. If you want only the date use trunc. So try: if trunc(:new.datum) = trunc(sysdate)

Comment: `plz   := (SELECT plz
                FROM plzverzeichnis
               WHERE ort = :new.ort);` you cannot assign a variable like that. You must use `into` clause.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Thanks for pointing that out, I missed that. On the plus side, I did get all of the other issues... I think.